# Alarm Manager + Notification actions

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I am trying to create a notification with two actions - Dismiss and Snooze but the first action is never called. I am trying the notification the following way:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(reminder.getName())
                    .setContentText(reminder.getNote())
                    .setLargeIcon(bigIcon)
                    .setWhen(when)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary))
                    .setSound(Uri.parse(ringtonePreference))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(reminder.getName()));
```

After that I will create pending intent for dismiss action.

```
private static PendingIntent createDismissIntent(Context context, GenericModel model) {
    int notificationId = ((Reminder) model).getNotificationId();
    Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(context, DismissReceiver.class);
    dismissIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
    dismissIntent.putExtra(MODEL_ID, model);

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, dismissIntent, 0);
}
```

Then I will create the pending intent for the snooze action.

```
private static PendingIntent createSnoozeIntent(Context context, GenericModel model) {
    int notificationId = ((Reminder) model).getNotificationId();
    Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(context, SnoozeReceiver.class);
    snoozeIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);

   return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, snoozeIntent, 0);
}
```

Then I add both actions to the notification builder.

```
builder.addAction(android.R.color.transparent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.dismiss), createDismissIntent(context, model));
    builder.addAction(android.R.color.transparent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.snooze), createSnoozeIntent(context, model));
```

After that I create pending intent for whole notification.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(notificationId, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I also created two broadcast receiver for each action but one of them is never called.